# Changing ToC subsection entry font in scrartcl

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, fontspec, koma-script, oldstylenums

I have changed the default serif font of my document to use old-style numerals (I think they look quite nice). However, in the serif entries of the subsections (section entries are in a sans-serif font) in the table of contents, the old-style numerals are quite strange as section and page numbers. I would like to change them to the "normal" numerals. I can set the section entry font with `\setkomafont{sectionentry}` and `\setkomafont{sectionentrypagenumber}`, but there is no such facility for other entries, and setting the font in the block around `\tableofcontents` doesn't help either.

How could I achive the effect I desire?

**EDIT**

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle,Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum}
\newfontfamily\NoOldStyleNumsSerif[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Libertine}

\begin{document}

{\NoOldStyleNumsSerif \tableofcontents}

\section{foo}

\subsection{bar}

Some text 0123456789

\end{document}
```

Notice that the page number is still rendered with old-style numerals:

[image: Example rendering]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Try: `setkomafont{disposition}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That would change the font in which section headings are written in the document, not in the TOC, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Werner I added an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't use `fontspec`, so there may be more elegant ways to do this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\tocmainfont{Cambria}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecfont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftsecpagefont}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsecfont}{\tocmainfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftsubsecpagefont}{\tocmainfont}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo}

\subsection{bar}

Some text 0123456789

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It indeed renders right with `tocloft`. Although I was hoping `scrartcl` could do this without additional packages.

Comment: @KristófMarussy You could use`tocstyle`. It’s a separate package, too, but part of the `KOMA-Script` bundle. When using you will get a warning, that it is in alpha state (according to the author it isn’t enough tested), but with KOMA-Script I didn't see any serious problems (I must admit, I used it with pdflatex only).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an suggestion which needs KOMA-Script version 3.20 or newer. No additional `toc` package is needed.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=OldStyle]{Cambria}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\newfontfamily\NoOldStyleNumsSerif{Cambria}

\newcommand\tocmainfont[1]{%
  \NoOldStyleNumsSerif #1%
}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  tocentrynumberformat=\tocmainfont,
  tocpagenumberformat=\tocmainfont
]{subsection,subsubsection}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\tocmainfont,
  pagenumberformat=\tocmainfont
]{default}{figure}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\tocmainfont,
  pagenumberformat=\tocmainfont
]{default}{table}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\section{foo}
Some text 0123456789
\subsection{bar}
\setcounter{subsection}{8}
\subsection{A figure caption}
\setcounter{figure}{8}
\captionof{figure}{Test}
\end{document}
```

[image]